# how i should update the email?

Tags: php, codeigniter

This is my validation for updating the email..

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'trim|required|valid_email|callback__unique_email[email]');
```

The call back function is

```
public function _unique_email($email) {
if ($this->crud_model->fetch_user_by_email_user_id($email,$this->session->userdata('user_id'))) {
    return true;
} else {
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'trim|required|valid_email|is_unique[users.email]');
        return true;
        return false;
    }
}
```

the email should be updated if the user changes the email in profile settings but if the user not makes any changes the email should be the old one and if he changes the email then it should be update by checking weather the email is unique in the database or not??

Answer (score 0):

```
    function index()
    {
        $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));

        $this->load->library('form_validation');

        $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'required|callback_email_check');

        if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
        {
            $this->load->view('form');
        }
        else
        {

            if($this->update($email)){
                 $this->load->view('formsuccess');
            }
        }
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
I haven't used codeIgniter for years, So I don't exactly know how things are there. But I'll try to answer your question on a general context and try to express that using the same code in your question with minor changes.

When You want to check if the user changed his email or not you need to have his old email from database first or in a hidden field of the form, then compare the email field value with the old one will make you know if he changed it.

Second you need to check if the email have duplicates on the database, remember you need to do this only if the user changed his email address, so just run a query with the database. if there are no existing email update the user email in database else display an error and quit.



public function is_unique_email($email) {
$old_email = $this->crud_model->fetch_user_email($this->session->userdata('user_id')); 
        if ($old_email == $email) {
            return true;
        } else {
                $duplicates = $this->crud_model->fetch_user_by_email($email);
              if(count($duplicates) > 0)
              {
                 return false;
              }
              else
              {
                return true;
              }
            }
        }
```

The end code should something similar to this, I'm sorry I can't give you the exact code, But I think you can run with this approach.

> I suggest you to move to some good frameworks like symfony, laravel or
>   zend. Codeigniter is not improved much from those early days where PHP
>   did a lot.